# Android アプリで「繰り返し停止しています」の原因は？

Tags: java, android

Android Studioでクイズアプリを作っているのですが、実機テストで「繰り返し停止しています」と表示されてしまいます。ググったところ、この`ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`が原因っぽく、quiz.txtのタブ文字入力を変えたり、配列の引数を確認しましたが、上手くいきません。
大変申し訳ありませんが、お力添えお願い致します。

**quiz.txt**

```
What is A?  A0  A1  A2
What is B?  B0  B1  B2
What is C?  C0  C1  C2
```

**MyQuiz.java**

```
package com.example.myquizapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class MyQuiz extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<String[]> quizSet = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    private TextView scoreText;
    private TextView qText;
    private Button a0Button;
    private Button a1Button;
    private Button a2Button;
    private Button nextButton;

    private int currentQuiz = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_quiz);

        loadQuizSet();

        getViews();

        setQuiz();
    }

    private void setQuiz(){
        qText.setText(quizSet.get(currentQuiz)[0]);

        ArrayList<String> answers;
        answers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++){
            answers.add(quizSet.get(currentQuiz)[i]);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(answers);

        a0Button.setText(answers.get(0));
        a1Button.setText(answers.get(1));
        a2Button.setText(answers.get(2));

        nextButton.setEnabled(false);
    }

    public void checkAnswer(View view){
        //answer
        Button clickedButton = (Button) view;
        String clickedAnswer = clickedButton.getText().toString();

        //judge
        if (clickedAnswer.equals(quizSet.get(currentQuiz)[1])){
            clickedButton.setText("〇" + clickedAnswer);
        } else {
            clickedButton.setText(("×" + clickedAnswer));
        }

        //button
        a0Button.setEnabled(false);
        a1Button.setEnabled(false);
        a2Button.setEnabled(false);
        nextButton.setEnabled(true);

        //next quiz
        currentQuiz++;
    }

    private void getViews(){
        scoreText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreText);
        qText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qText);
        a0Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a0Button);
        a1Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a1Button);
        a2Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a2Button);
        nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
    }

    private void loadQuizSet(){
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try{
            inputStream = getAssets().open("quiz.txt");
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String s;
            while ((s = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                quizSet.add(s.split("\t"));
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try{
                if (inputStream != null) inputStream.close();
                if (bufferedReader != null) bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
2020-10-05 23:24:09.026 8966-8966/? E/ample.myquizap: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-10-05 23:24:12.330 8966-8966/com.example.myquizapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myquizapp, PID: 8966
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myquizapp/com.example.myquizapp.MyQuiz}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
        at com.example.myquizapp.MyQuiz.setQuiz(MyQuiz.java:48)
        at com.example.myquizapp.MyQuiz.onCreate(MyQuiz.java:39)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: quiz.txtはタブ区切りになってますか? デバッガやロガーなどを使ってquizSetに期待さてているデータが入っているか確認してみてください。

Comment: デバッカを使うと、明らかにquiz.txtのタブが効いてないので、設定>java>タブ文字を使用＞スマートタブ、にチェックを入れる、を行ってもタブが入力されず、半角スペースが2つ入る状態になってしまいます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決できました。
txtファイルだったので、javaのタブ設定ではなく、その他ファイルのタブ文字設定にチェックを入れたら、エラーが解除されました。
感謝です。

Comment: 解決できて良かったです。ご自身で原因を調べた手順や解決方法を「回答」として書いて、その回答を自分で承認していただけますか?

Comment: ありがとうございます！！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

解決できました。 txtファイルだったので、「java」のタブ設定ではなく、「その他ファイル」のタブ文字設定にチェックを入れたら、エラーが解除されました。